# proguard not working with adt 22.0.1 (only Mac)

Tags: android, macos, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate the code by enabling proguard in Mac but I get an error .After the update to adt 22.0.1 and after other updates

sometimes: `error code 1 when proguard.config=proguard.cfg and`

sometimes Unable to access jarfile /Volumes/New
 when

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

But it was working perfectly in the previous adt and it AND THE SAME CODE RUNS PERFECTLY ON WINDOWS BUT NOT IN MAC.. WHY??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths probably need forward slashes in MacOS.